# Marginalize a multivariate lambda function

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I have a function f depending on a variable number of arguments. For the sake of example, let’s say it depends on 4 arguments.

```
f = lambda x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4: *function’s body*
```

Given a arbitrary tuple t of integers and of size 3, I would like to evaluate the function f on this tuple by leaving out an argument every time:

```
f_1 = lambda x_1 : f(x_1,*t)
f_2 = lambda x_2 : f(t[0],x_2, *t[1:])
f_3 = lambda x_3 : f(t[0],t[1],x_3, *t[2:])
f_4 = lambda x_4 : f(*t,x_4)
```

Is there a generic method to compute those function, for an arbitrary number of arguments ? I would like to loop over the arguments, but it seems rather cumbersome to bind the values, especially when the number of arguments is variable.

This would help me to compute the marginales of a function. I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1):

`make_subfunctions` take a function and a list of fixed arguments, and return a list of sub-functions that accepts one argument.

1. The resultant functions should call the original function with `f(*fixed_args[:i], the_only_argument, *fixed_args[i:])`. We need a `wrapper()` or a proxy to do this work.
2. The `fixed_args[:i]` and `fixed_args[i:]` are fixed for each wrapper, we can use `functools.partial` to pre-fill those two arguments, and let the caller fill the rest dynamic argument. Thus, the wrapper signature is `(head, tail, x)`.
3. The `start` and `last` arguments specify the (inclusive) index of the dynamic argument being insert to the fixed arguments.

Output:

```
('a', 0, 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 3)
```

```py
from functools import partial


def make_subfunctions(f, fixed_args, start=0, last=None):
    fixed_args = tuple(fixed_args)

    if last is None:
        last = len(fixed_args)

    def wrapper(head, tail, x):
        return f(*head, x, *tail)

    fns = [partial(wrapper, fixed_args[:i], fixed_args[i:]) for i in range(start, last + 1)]

    return fns


def hello_world(*args):
    print(args)


def main():
    fixed_args = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    fns = make_subfunctions(hello_world, fixed_args, start=1)

    for i in range(len(fns)):
        fns[i](i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```